# Blocking Control Panel, Administrative Tools for specific users when connected via Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, windows-terminal-services

I've setup Terminal Server on Windows Server 2003. I have problem with permission on this server. On server I have administrator account and some user accounts.

How can I block Control Panel, Administrative Tools, command prompt etc only for user which will be connecting via Remote Desktop?

I need allow Control Panel, Administrative Tools etc for Administartor and have them blocked only for some group.

I tried it in `gpedit.msc` but it's blocked for an Admin account.

Is there a simple tool for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure a GPO with the restrictions you want and use Security Filtering to apply it to a specific group of users that does not include the Administrator account.